# Want to create serial numbers

Tags: oracle, sas, numbers, sequence

I want to generate the serial no.s

e.g.

I have,

```
NID
----- 
ABD90
BGJ89
HSA76
```

and I want,

```
ID NID
---------
1  ABD90 
2  BGJ89
3  HSA76
```

What code should I run for this outcome?
Please help me.

Comment: Are you struggling with a SQL query or some other code? Please show us what you are working on.

Comment: Take a loot at either [row_number() over()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytic function or [rownum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) pseudocolumn or (these ones behave a bit different)[rank() over()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) or [dense_rank() over()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm) analytic functios

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged SAS, I'll answer with SAS.

Based on your question, getting that result from that input would be as simple as this

```
data result;
  ID=_N_;
  set input;
run;
```

or

```
proc sql;
  select ID as monotonic()
        ,NID
  from input
  ;
quit;
```

In pure Oracle you would do this

```
select rownum, NID
from input
```

However you might want to throw on ORDER BY in there because you'll likely get different results every time you run that.